# How can I access the public data on a user's profile page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, permissions, profile

For argument's sake say we have a person who has made almost everything on their page public - workplace, hometown, location, birthday, email, phone number, posts etc.

How can I access this information using the graph API?

Currently I am using `$facebook->api('/'.$id;` which returns id, first_name, last_name, link, gender, locale and updated_time.

Comment: You have to use the `fields` parameter – https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/

Comment: That does not work. I have tried using the Graph API explorer on the facebook dev site, using the string `100005254861029?fields=education`
I only get returned `{
  "id": "100005254861029"
}`

Comment: And what does it say on the doc page in the "Permissions" column ...? Aha, there you go.

Comment: user_education_history is selected by default anyway..

Answer (score 0):

Else you can try 3rd party services like LoginRadius which can provide you with ready to use code to get all these details

Comment: I want to get the public details from other profiles, rather than that of the user.